# Redraw a Jquery Datatable using aoData

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have setup a datatable. This table is generated serverside using 1 parameter. once i add/edit or delete something in the table, I need to redraw the table. But I can't get it working. I was using .fnDraw() function, but as I understand this dosen't work, with server side tables.

The value of the parameter hasen't changed. My table looks like this:

```
varTable = $("#varTable").dataTable({
    'bPaginate': false,
    'bAutoWidth': false,
    'bFilter': false,
    'aaSorting': [[0, "asc"]],
    'bInfo': false,
    'bServerSide': true,
    'sAjaxSource': $("#varTable").attr('data-action-url'),
    "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        aoData.push({ "name": "stringAppID", "value": selectedAppId });
    },
    'aoColumns': [
                        {
                            'mData': 'Name',
                            'bSortable': false
                        }
                     ]
});
```

Anyone know how I can refresh the table?

Comment: just to make it clear, you want to update the contents of the table whenever there is new record inserted in the database? like a real-time app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fnReloadAjax();` to reload table data from its ajax source

Suppose you got a button with `refreshButtonID`

```
$("#refreshButtonID").click(function() {
    varTable.fnReloadAjax();
});
```

You can take this datatables plugin source from here [fnReloadAjax](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api) , drop it in some js file and include it in your page...

Comment: Thanks. Had tried this, with no luck.
No i try it again and it workd... Somehow having a stackoverflowder, makes computer say "Yes".